# AspNetCore web api. .net core 7 запуск из консоли

Tags: консоль, asp.net-core

Подскажите, как при запуске из консоли, указать приложению (WebApi) путь до директории где лежат appsettings.json конфигурационные файлы.

Мне нужно запускать приложение не из той папки где располагается сама программа, а из другой папки. и при запуске сейчас ругается на то что не может найти файлы appsettings.json.

Подскажите, какой входной параметр нужно передать что бы указать путь до папки корректной ?

Comment: Есть такое понятие - Рабочий каталог, это некое место, в котором некоторые приложения ищут, и в которое пишут данные. Если вы условно открыли консоль и прописали туда сразу полный путь до вашего проекта, без перехода в папку, то вашим рабочим каталогом будет то место, которое указано в консоли перед командой (`C:\Dir> ...` - вот `C:\Dir` - это рабочий каталог). Собственно, задайте этот каталог (зависит от того, как вы запускаете), и должно все находить. Правда зависит от того, как идет поиск пути, он может совсем не смотреть на раб. каталог...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, Вам нужно:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)
...
builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(*Ваш путь до директории с файлами конфигурации*).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
```

(см. [ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0))